# How to copy built assemblies into a project resource folder?

Tags: c#, .net

In the Resources folder of my project, I have many different DLLs from other assemblies in my solution. These DLLs are used as embedded resources so I can have a single EXE without having to have local copies of all the DLLs. What I want to be able to do is have them updated every time I build my entire solution. So for example, if I have AssemblyOne/bin/x86/Debug/Foo.dll, I want the DLL to always copy over to LocalAssembly/Resources/Foo.dll whenever I build the project.

Is there an easy way to do this? I was looking at the post-build-event macros, but none of them would be able to directly reference my "LocalAssembly", which is not the Solution Directory. Also, I'm not sure how I would go about writing a new custom post-build command in a way that the newly copied DLLs would not be an absolute reference to my local machine. Thanks! Please comment for more information and I will edit the question.

Comment: You can address LocalAssembly by using ../../.. or something similar in the post-build event, relative to your solution's directory.  Is that not sufficient?

Comment: On startup project right click on your assembly and click properties the select build action to embed as resources

Comment: @YYY I will give that a try and see what happens

Comment: @Lanel I will go ahead and make an answer about that explaining it a little further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not access only your solution folder in post build events.  The post build scripts run with whatever permissions the compiler had when it ran.  Since in Visual Studio things frequently run with Administrator permissions, chances are great you have access to your entire file system.  As a result, if you are wanting to copy resources around, you merely need to presume that you are starting the `xcopy` call in the build destination directory.  From there, you can navigate around with normal paths.  So if, for example, you needed go up three levels and then into the directory `LocalAssemblies`, your copy command would look like `xcopy Foo.dll ../../../LocalAssemblies`.